# Safe programming with marker interfaces vs. the Liskov substitution principle

Tags: php, oop

I know about the LSP and why the following code gives:

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
>   UnauthenticatedUser::executeCommand(UnauthenticatedCommand $c) must be
>   compatible with User::executeCommand(Command $c) in /tmp/test.php on
>   line 13

However, I would argue that the two interfaces `Command` and `UnauthenticatedCommand` are equivalent (since they're just marker interfaces).

Given these facts, what would be a clean<sup>[1]</sup> approach for making it impossible for an unauthenticated user to execute anything else but an `UnauthenticatedCommand`?

```
<?php

interface Command {
}

interface UnauthenticatedCommand extends Command {
}

interface User {
    public function executeCommand(Command $c);
}

class UnauthenticatedUser implements User {
    public function executeCommand(UnauthenticatedCommand $c) {
    }
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> clean meaning not using introspection, neither programmatically nor with the engine's support (`instanceof`).

Comment: While your reasoning is not particularly unreasonable, it's not something that PHP supports. Your best bet is to hint on the `Command` interface and then add an additional `instanceof` constraint in the method body.

Comment: @Sammitch It would be really nice and beneficial for all of us to have your comment as an answer.

Comment: Assuming PHP will let you declare classes as you wrote them. How should `(new UnauthenticatedUser())->execute(new InsanceOfCommand())` work? `InsanceOfCommand` is __NOT__ implementing `UnauthenticatedCommand`

Comment: @mleko it would throw a throwable, and get logged with emergency level.

Comment: @Flavius so you want it to be `TypeError`?

Comment: Yes, but enforced at the language level.

Comment: @Flavius by `UnauthenticatedCommand` you mean commad without credentials or command that don't need to be authenticated?

Comment: @mleko Where is the difference between the two options you're asking about? An `UnauthenticatedCommand` is a command which can be executed by unauthenticated users.

Comment: @Flavius it also can be a command which needs to be authenticated before further processing. BTW why you want to controll access using inheritance, shouldn't this be covered by ACL layer?

Comment: @mleko as the subject of the question states, for "safer programming". I can get away with `instanceof`, it works just fine, I was just wondering if it's possible at the language level.

Comment: @Flavius I would say that doing ACL with inheritance is bad design, but maybe I lack some of context

Comment: It's not ACL, really. There's another layer on top of this for that. It's really just safe(r) programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
interface Command {
}

interface UnauthenticatedCommand extends Command {
}

interface User {
   // some general methods
}

interface AuthenticatedUser implements User {
   public function executeCommand(Command $c);
}

interface UnauthenticatedUser implements User {
   public function executeCommand(UnauthenticatedCommand $c);
}
```